# Параллельный запуск selenium WebDriver теста одновременно 10-30 раз

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, internet-explorer, testng

Не получается запустить 10-30 раз, один тест одновременно(в дальнейшем рассматриваю 1000 потоков, пока 10-30 пробую), попробовал с @Test(threadPoolSize = 10), но он не одновременно выполняет, а последовательно 10 раз. Мне нужно 10 раз одновременно запустить, как бы эмуляция 10 пользователей. Или есть другие способы?

```
public class TestNg {

public static WebDriver webDriver;

@BeforeTest
public void setUp(){
    File file = new File("D:/ieDriver/IEDriverServer.exe");
    System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", file.getAbsolutePath());

    webDriver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
}

@Test(threadPoolSize = 10)
public void programiz(){

    webDriver.get("https://www.programiz.com/java-programming");
    webDriver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/main/div[5]/div/div/div/div[1]/a")).click();
}


@AfterTest
public void close(){
    webDriver.quit();
}
```

}

Comment: а как так - драйвер (читай браузер) один, а эмуляция 10 пользователей?

Comment: К примеру 10 потоков, и 10 запусков браузера одновременно

Comment: ну так а обычный цикл от 0 до 10 нельзя сделать? и в нем создавать браузер